# How commonly is the neologistic word “опция” used as a variant of "вариант"?

Tags: выбор-слова

> В таком случае помни, что есть масса **опций**: ты всегда можешь воспользоваться доставкой цветов — пусть даже ты вообще в другом городе.

Here, "масса опций" is used with the meaning of "tons of options", and I'm wondering if the word "опция" is sufficiently widely adopted to be considered a common Russian word rather than a fad.

I'm used to hearing my girlfriend say "вариант" instead, as in "масса вариантов", and as far as I remember, I've never heard her use "опция".

Comment: it's pretty standard amongst population working in the IT and programming industry

Comment: and for some reason it is common in sales

Answer (score 4):

*Опция* is quite common in the areas heavily influenced by English, such as IT industry, car sales, mobile networking and telecom. It is a calque from English "option" as in "car option" or "mobile plan option". Before its advent, *дополнительная услуга, дополнительное оборудование, параметр* etc. were used in the same sense.

The first usage recorded in the corpus is from 2002, in Google Books from 1986. All usages prior to 2005 I could find are exclusive to the areas listed above. After 2005, the word seems to gain enough traction to be used as a metonymy:

> - 3 января 2015 года истекает максимальный срок содержания Урлашова под стражей во время следствия, стало быть, надо либо судить, либо выпускать. Вторая опция всерьез никем не рассматривается, в городе ждут ясности по первой.
> - Ноги – главная опция для секса, а не для семьи.
> - Ещё одна новинка музея ― работу по подготовке экспозиции второго зала посетители могут наблюдать «за стеклом». Эта «опция» пользуется огромной популярностью.

All those are deliberate metonymies.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's widely used. When we say "widely ", we mean "everywhere ", universally.  Perhaps in science, in specific fields, but not in everyday speech.  We use **варианты, большой выбор, масса возможностей** instead.

Comment: I believe it's rather widely used for a different meaning, a small addition to something (e.g. "тариф "плати больше" имеет следующие опции: "дополнительный пакет минут", "бесплатные смс", "безлимитный интернет для магазина приложений"")